# How to get store multiple values from a string

Tags: python, string

I am working with the yelp dataset. In that is a dictionary for the schedule of multiple restaurants.

They are sorted as shown below:

```
{'Friday': '8:0-23:0',
 'Monday': '8:0-22:0',
 'Saturday': '8:0-23:0',
 'Sunday': '8:0-22:0',
 'Thursday': '8:0-22:0',
 'Tuesday': '8:0-22:0',
 'Wednesday': '8:0-22:0'}
```

I want to get the timespan for each day by subtracting the closing time from the opening time and then get the sum of all of them. However, I am struggling to do the subtraction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the expected output(s)?

Comment: What's your question exactly? What have you already tried and where are you stuck? If you can already parse out the hours from the strings, please save us the hassle and give us that code. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Is the problem that you have the math wrong? You should be subtracting the **opening** time from the **closing** time.

Comment: Clarify where you are having trouble.  Show what code you have and where you are stuck.  What is the expected outcome?  100 hours?

Answer (score 1):

you can **loop** over the dict values and `.split("-")` the value to a list. This creates the two values per day. Then, remove the last two (`:0`) by loop in over the `values` in the `list` with `my_list[value] = my_list[value][:-2]`.

Now you have a list with only the numbers you are looking for. **cast** them to `int` and perform the subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

```
dc = {'Friday': '8:0-23:0',
 'Monday': '8:0-22:0',
 'Saturday': '8:0-23:0',
 'Sunday': '8:0-22:0',
 'Thursday': '8:0-22:0',
 'Tuesday': '8:0-22:0',
 'Wednesday': '8:0-22:0'}

sum_elapsed = 0
for _, v in dc.items():
    start, end = v.split('-')
    hhs, mms = (int(v) for v in start.split(':'))
    hhe, mme = (int(v) for v in end.split(':'))
    elapsed = (hhe * 60 + mme) - (hhs * 60 + mms) 
    sum_elapsed += elapsed

print(sum_elapsed)
```

Comment: Working fine. It will be nicer to indicate the time *unit* instead of *6000*... ;-)